# how to hide splash when the app is coming back from background?

Tags: ios, multitasking

I just set the 'Application does not run in background' parameter of my ios app to NO and I added the relevant refreshes in applicationDidBecomeActive: in my application delegate then it works pretty well. But when I switch back to my app, the splash screen still appear during one second. How to remove it and display directly the app ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent Splash Screen from showing after returning from background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143151/prevent-splash-screen-from-showing-after-returning-from-background)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I though it was impossible, but it remembered me this topic : [Prevent Splash Screen from showing after returning from background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143151/prevent-splash-screen-from-showing-after-returning-from-background)

It seems to include an answer to your question...
Also, don't forget to try on the device, sometimes the simulator does weird things.