# iOS Default.png always comes up on some devices

Tags: ios

I have an app and the Default.png images always comes up on some devices when coming back from background. 
It would seem to be happening for apps that were created after I upgraded to XCode 4.6.1.

I tried the solution suggested here:
[IOS Default.png show every time when my app enter foreground from background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285787/ios-default-png-show-every-time-when-my-app-enter-foreground-from-background)
and no go.

If I run the app on iPhone 5 with 6.1.4, the Default only comes up once when the app is initially launched. After that, it never comes up.
If I run the app on my iPad 3 with 6.1.3, the Default always comes up after coming back from background.
My QA lead sees the issue on her iPad 3 with 6.1.4.

Did they change something in the XCode project settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by chance here:

[Prevent Splash Screen from showing after returning from background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143151/prevent-splash-screen-from-showing-after-returning-from-background)

Turns out I had set UIStatusBarStyle in my info.plist and that caused the issue on iPad 3.

Answer (score 0):

Genrally Your App Enter in to Foreground ,IOS 5 simulator displays a Lunch Image where IOS 4.3 simulator take a screen shot of the App when it was entering in to background , but testing on real device its work perfect.

Comment: I am not talking about simulator. I am seeing the behaviour on real devices.